# Having problems with righting memory with pymem

Tags: python, python-3.x

Error with righting memory pymem csgo, not sure what line it is as it wont show full traceback, please help me fix my code.

Error `Could not read memory at: -63746652, length: 4 - GetLastError: 998`

Code

```
from Utils.Offsets import *

def GetPlayerVars(pm, client, engine, engine_pointer, player):
    try:
        player = pm.read_int( client + dwLocalPlayer )
        engine_pointer = pm.read_int( engine + dwClientState )
        glow_manager = pm.read_int( client + dwGlowObjectManager )
        crosshairID = pm.read_int( player + m_iCrosshairId )
        getcrosshairTarget = pm.read_int( client + dwEntityList + (crosshairID - 1) * 0x10 )
        immunitygunganme = pm.read_int( getcrosshairTarget + m_bGunGameImmunity )
        localTeam = pm.read_int( player + m_iTeamNum )
        crosshairTeam = pm.read_int( getcrosshairTarget + m_iTeamNum )
        y_angle = pm.read_float( engine_pointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4 )
    except Exception as e:
        return print(e)

    return player, engine_pointer, glow_manager, crosshairID, getcrosshairTarget,immunitygunganme, localTeam, crosshairTeam, y_angle
```

Comment: Of cause it won't show any traceback if you have and unconditional exception handling that just prints the error.

Comment: maybe this is helpful or related [reddit  learnpython Pymem "Could not write memory"](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ng4oqb/pymem_could_not_write_memory/)

Comment: do you mean error writing memory?